# Ubuntu goes black on startup

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8.1, grub, ubuntu-14.04, black-screen-of-death

Whenever I start Ubuntu from the GRUB menu (below).

[image]

and it finishes this (below).

[image]

The screen goes black. This happened after I gained root access to my account and I needed to restart. After this the screen goes completely black (no backlight). I dual-booted Ubuntu with my Windows 8.1 32-bit OS. What do I do?

Comment: Is the computer still on?  Are you using digital video or VGA?  It sounds like your graphics card is in a mode not supported by your monitor.

Comment: The computer is still on and I am using a laptop with no VGA and when I press the power button the Ubuntu logo shows and the PC shuts down.

Comment: @Brad makes a good point. Try pushing "e" to edit grub entry, and add a space followed by "vga=788" which should force it to 800x600 resultion with 16-bit colour.

Comment: Then fix the resolution in the settings?

Comment: It was working but it stopped after that 1 time.

Comment: I don't think the changes you make from the GRUB menu are permanent. If you want to change it permanently the file is usually `/boot/grub/menu.lst`.